# What steps are requried to upgrade from Angular2 RC2 to RC4

Tags: angular

What steps are required to upgrade an existing Angular2 RC2 app to RC4? I've updated my package.json file like so (see below) and have run npm update on the root folder but it still references the old versions of the angular packages in node modules folder from RC2.

Ive checked the change logs and release notes and searched google but to no avail. The app runs but crashes when referencing the new ngModel related form functionality that also wasn't working in RC2. Im trying to update to RC4 to use the new forms module to see if that resolves my underlying form issue.

**Original**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.0",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

**Modified**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli for your project ?

Comment: Not yet, but planning to - would that help?

Comment: angular-cli is a great tool to use, I have updated my code from rc1 to rc4. No issue from my side. Can you do `npm install` instead of update ?

Comment: Im running `npm install -g angular-cli` right now - what should I do next?

Comment: just `ng new project_name` , then `cd project_name` and `npm install`, there you go. Finally dont forget to `ng serve` to run the code

Comment: Thats cool but I need to update my current app not create a new one

Comment: as I said can you try `npm install` instead of update in your project directory

Comment: Apologies, i didn't connect the dots there - I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do `npm install` instead of update in your project directory?

Comment: So for the upgrade in the end I updated my dependancies in packages.json (removed the commented lines) deleted node_module folder and then ran npm install! Seems to have also fixed my underlying form issue too - which is nice. Thanks for all the help!